# Question views shown are incorrect

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Views to my question [Get Date Object In UTC format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091107/get-date-object-in-utc-format-in-java) crossed 1500. But under my profile in questions sub tab it is showing "2K view"

[image: 2k views]

Is it a bug ?

Comment: The number is rounded.

Comment: In my honest opinion it should display the highest *achieved* view count, for example, anything between 1000 and 2000 would show `1k`.

Comment: Related on MSE: [10k Views Badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192667/10k-views-badge) and [Wrong view count for questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14118/wrong-view-count-for-questions).

Comment: The hover-text on the rounded view count shows the exact view count. Just FYI. Good hint that this is not a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We round up. 1.5 rounded up is 2...

Comment: Please log this as a change request, then.